# Short exact sequence of linear representations of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a group with $V',V,V''$ being representations of $G$. Let $$0
{\longrightarrow}V'
{\longrightarrow}V\overset{v}{\longrightarrow}V''\longrightarrow
 0\tag{1} $$ be a short exact sequence of $K$-vector spaces and homomorphisms. Then $v$ is a surjection. 
For any representation of G, say V, we define
 $$\pi(x) := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} g(x)$$   $\forall x\in V$.

and$$ V^G:=\{x\in V:   s.x=x, \forall s\in G\}$$

To show that $\forall x''\in V''^G, \exists x\in V^G$ such that $v(x)=x'' $.
 The proof in the book I am reading is as follows,
$$v(\pi(x))=\pi(v(x)=v(x)=x'')$$

My question is that

1. Aren't $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(x'')$ in the images of two different $\pi$ functions, one defined on $V$ other on $V''$?
2. Why is $\pi$ commuting with $v$?

Comment: Sure that (1) is only a sequence of $K$-vector spaces, not of $G$-representations? That is, we have that $v(gx) = g\,v(x)$ for $x \in V$.

Comment: $K$ is the field over which the vector spaces are defined, here it is $C$, the complex numbers. All of the vector spaces are representations of G. Does that mean $v(gx)=gv(x)$?

Comment: No. That is not automatically true, but your result will only hold, if you assume that $v$ is not only a $K$-linear map, but moreover is compatible with the $G$-module structure on $V$, $V''$.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @martini J.P Serre's Groupe fini.

Comment: Serre wants the maps to be $G$-homomorphisms, he writes in [https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwi2tJ6Xi8TIAhXIwHIKHUdsBF8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.college-de-france.fr%2Fmedia%2Fjean-pierre-serre%2FUPL2937151343298039815_1___Groupes_finis.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEFBxktqVMuN3IYJLGI_lfYoPgYrg&sig2=8DR4nQoqpk8zu1NQhYptkg&bvm=bv.105039540,d.bGQ&cad=rja]

Comment: @martini It was written "représentations de G" which I took to be "linear representations of G" and assumed that they are just any vector spaces which are representations of G.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30296/discussion-between-martini-and-neerajkumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the maps in (1) aren't compatible with the repesentations $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$, $\mathrm{GL}(V')$, $\mathrm{GL}(V'')$, the result is not true, so in the following, we suppose, that (1) is a short exact sequence of $G$-representations and homomorphisms.

Serre also writes in the statement of this [Corollary (page 61, Corollaire A.3)](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwi2tJ6Xi8TIAhXIwHIKHUdsBF8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.college-de-france.fr%2Fmedia%2Fjean-pierre-serre%2FUPL2937151343298039815_1___Groupes_finis.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEFBxktqVMuN3IYJLGI_lfYoPgYrg&sig2=8DR4nQoqpk8zu1NQhYptkg&bvm=bv.105039540,d.bGQ) (emphasis added)

> Soit $$ 0 \to V' \to  V \stackrel v\to V'' \to 0 $$
>   une suite exacte de **représentations de $G$**.
>   Alors tout élément de $V''^G$ est image d’un élément de $V^G$.

That is, by definition, we have that 
$$ v(g.x) = g.v(x), \quad g \in G, x \in V $$

For any homomorphism of $G$-representations, $\phi\colon V\to W$ note that $\phi$ commutes with the respective $\pi$s. We have for $x \in V$:
\begin{align*}
   (\phi \circ \pi_V)(x) &= \phi\left(\frac 1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} gx\right)\\
            &= \frac 1{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \phi(gx)\\
            &= \frac 1{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} g\phi(x) \text{ as $\phi$ is a $G$-homomorphism}\\
            &= (\pi_W \circ \phi)(x)
\end{align*}
Now everything works fine: Let $x'' \in V''^G$, then $\pi_{V''}(x'') = x''$. Choose, as $v$ is onto $x \in V$ with $v(x) = x''$. We have 
$$ v\pi_V(x) = \pi_{V''}\bigl(v(x)\bigr) = \pi_{V''}(x'') = x''. $$

Comment: Hmm.. I see. Thanks a lot.